# Getting error trying to start ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I created a new app with ruby on rails and tried to start it, then got this error.

1 - have ruby-dev-kit

2 - ruby version 2.7.0

Tried to fix this error in many ways. I use Linux

Traceback

```
       11: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/nodes.rb:2:in `<main>'
        10: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
         9: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         8: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
         7: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         6: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
         5: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/psych/nodes/node.rb:2:in `<main>'
         4: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
         3: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         2: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
         1: from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': superclass mismatch for class StringIO (TypeError)
```

Comment: You have tagged this question with [tag:ruby-on-rails-3]. Are you actually using version 3? The latest is 6.1. The latest supported is 5.2. You should not start a new project with version 3.

Comment: I think he meant ruby version, not rails, got it mixed up. By the way, it's also good to mention here what version manager, package manager, Linus OS version you're using. What have you done so far to fix the issue. I highly suggest following this guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so it's easier to be assisted by the community.

Answer (score -1):

The method is already defined somewhere else

You can test that by using the `defined?` method and update gem version accordingly.

Comment: how can this method be run if a rails console can't be launched?